# If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $f^3(x)=x$, then $ f(x)=x$

Tags: analysis, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [3rd iterate of a continuous function equals identity function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/3rd-iterate-of-a-continuous-function-equals-identity-function)

Assume $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$  is  continuous and $f^3(x)=x $ $\forall x$. How can I prove that$$\forall x\in\mathbb R,\ f(x)=x$$

Comment: By $f^3(x)$ do you mean $\big(f(x)\big)^3$, or $f\big(f\big(f(x)\big)\big)$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It would have to be the latter. Otherwise let $f(x)=x^{1/3}$. But I agree the notation is ambiguous.

Comment: @brian-m-scotti: mean f(f(f(X)))

Comment: thanks merico i don't know  this  question posted by lorenz-chaos i receive my answer(im sorry )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $f \circ f^2= \operatorname{Id}$, $f$ is bijective; so $f$ is monotonic, because $f$ is continuous. Without loss of generality, suppose $f$ increasing.

Now, suppose that there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>x$. Then $f^2(x)>f(x)$ and $f^3(x)>f^2(x)$; hence $x=f^3(x)> f^2(x)>f(x)>x$, a contradiction.

Comment: I believe one should justify why $f$ is increasing: $f$ decreasing $\implies f^2$ increasing $\implies f^3$ decreasing which contradicts with $f^3 = Id$.