# What are the $n$th roots of the identity function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

What are all the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^n=I$ where $f^n$ denotes the composition $f\circ f\circ f\dots \circ f$ of $f$ with itself $n$ times, and $I:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the identity function?

Is there a neat description of such functions? (There seems to be infinitely many of them, for each $n>1$.)

It is easy to see that such a $f$ has to be bijective.

Is there a better answer if $f$ is assumed to be continuous?

Comment: The answer left by Alex Becker (here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/3rd-iterate-of-a-continuous-function-equals-identity-function ) appears easily generalizable to prove that if $f$ is continuous then it is $\pm I$, with $-I$ only available for even $n$, of course :)

Comment: I don't think there is a useful general answer to this question. Of course every number sits in a ``cycle'' of length a divisor of $n$, but that seems like all you can really say. Perhaps by using a weaker form of continuity you can get a less unwieldy class of functions.

Comment: @EricStucky I don't get the first comment, for $f(x)=-(1/2)x, x\geq 0, f(x)=-2x, x<0$, for instance, is continuous, and has identity as its square, isn't it?

Comment: @N: Yes, that is true. I thought I remembered that the only continuous square root was $-I$ but that's obviously wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: @EricStucky Is it that they are the only ones *up to some nice equivalence relation*? (In view of mercio's answer)

Comment: @N: I don't think that's what I was remembering, but perhaps it is true anyway. I'll give it some thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you suppose that $f$ has to be continuous, then since it is bijective, it is monotonous.

If $f$ is increasing then $f = id$ : suppose not, then there is an $x$ such that $f(x) \neq x$. Suppose $f(x) > x$. Then $x = f^{\circ n}(x) > \ldots > f(f(x)) > f(x) > x$, which is a contradiction. The case when $f(x) < x$ works the same way.

If $n$ is odd then $f$ can't be decreasing so $f$ is increasing and $f = id$.

If $n$ is even then $f$ can be decreasing. Then $f^2$ is an $n/2$-th root of the identity and increasing, so $f^2 = id$.

So we are left to determine the continuous decreasing solutions to $f^2 = id$. Such a $f$ has a unique fixpoint $x_0$. You can define $f$ on $[x_0 ; \infty)$ in any way you want (as long as it's a bijection on $(-\infty ; x_0]$), then you have to extend $f$ on $(-\infty ; x_0]$ in a unique way with $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.

---

If you don't require $f$ to be continuous then such a $f$ can be obtained by partitioning $\Bbb R$ into finite sets $S_k = \{x_1^k,\ldots,x_{d_k}^k\}$ of cardinality $d_k$ with $d_k \mid n$, and then setting $f(x_i^k) = x_{i+1}^k$ and $f(x_{d_k}^k) = x_1^k$. There are many many possible functions then.

Comment: I should have added $f$ is to be continuous.

Comment: So there is just one odd root but there are infinitely many even roots. Is there a natural equivalence relation on the set of all (continuous) functions that reduces the answer to just two even roots, I and -I?

Comment: I guess if you consider conjugation classes by homeomorphisms of $\Bbb R$ ? Say $f_1 \sim f_2$ when there exists a homeomorphism $h$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $f_1 \circ h = h \circ f_2$. Then for even $n$ the decreasing $n$th roots of the identity are exactly the equivalence class of $-I$, and the increasing ones are the equivalence class of $I$ (which is just $I$). So really they are all the same up to renaming the elements of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Very much true. Shall we add this to the question and answer?

Comment: And how to find all real analytic real valued $f$ with $f(f(x))=x$?