# Can we find two different real functions f and g such that f is a composition of g's and g is a composition of f's?

Tags: functions

Can we find two different real functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f$ is a composition of $g$'s and $g$ is a composition of $f$'s? ($f,g \; \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R})$.

My ideas: Well, if f is a composition of g's and g is a composition of f's what we are really looking for is an $f$ such that $f^n=f$ and $n$ is not prime. So it would be sufficient to find pretty much any function that satisfied $f^n=x$, however all the ones I could find had domain problems i.e $\tan ^{-1}(\tan(x)+\pi/m)$ or something.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Any continuous function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ that satisfies $f^n(x) = x$ for $n > 0$ must satisfy $f(x) = x$ or $f(f(x)) = x$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842403/what-are-the-nth-roots-of-the-identity-function .

Comment: A priori, though, this appears to be a stronger condition than the first one you mention.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require $f$ and $g$ continuous, then take

$f(x) = x + 1 \mod 3$

$g(x) = x + 2 \mod 3$

(where by $y \mod 3$ we mean the unique real number $z$ with $y = 3n + z$, some $n \in \mathbb Z$, and $0 \leq z < 3$)

Then $f(f(x)) = g(x)$ and $g(g(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.