# Find all functions for which $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in D$

Tags: analysis, functions

I just came across a nice coincidence with regular polygons. To check if a polygon with $n$ sides can completely occupy a surface, it must hold that the integer multiple of the interior angle $\alpha = \pi - 2\pi/n$ gives exactly $2\pi$. Say:
\begin{align*}
k \cdot (\pi - 2\pi/n) = 2\pi  
\end{align*}
By rearranging you then find:
\begin{align*}
k = \frac{2n}{n-2}, \hspace{30pt} n = \frac{2k}{k-2}
\end{align*}
It follows that this only works with triangles, squares, and hexagons. However, I do not want to go into that now. I noticed that the function
\begin{align*}
f(x) =\frac{2x}{x-2}
\end{align*}
has the strange property $f(x) = y$, $f(y) = x$. Means: $f(f(x)) =x \ $ or $\ f^{-1} = f$. Are there any other functions of this type? Ignoring the trivial answer $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Every involutive function has the desied property. Indeed, a involutive function is definided by $f\circ f =id$. Thus, if $f(x)=y$, then $f(y)=f\circ f(x)=x$.

Comment: If you do not impose any condition in $f$, there are many examples, like: $$a-x,$$ $$a/x,$$ $$\frac{1}{x-a}+a.$$

Comment: Okay, so lots of solutions. Are they infinite or are they finite? (would be my next question). And is there a certain pattern that these functions follow?

Comment: There are a uncountable number of such functions! There not exists a pattern. Observe that the function $$f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\right)$$ is a example too.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842403/what-are-the-nth-roots-of-the-identity-function): covers the case where $f$ is continuous and $D = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you are interested of such functions, look the Charles Babbage works, he studied such function in 1815. Look for Babbage's functional equation.

Comment: @DiegoMath Your fourth example does work. I get the following by rearranging:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{ae^x+b}{ce^x+d}\right) = y \hspace{10pt} \Longrightarrow \hspace{10pt} x = \ln\left(\frac{-de^x+b}{ce^x-a}\right) 
\end{align*}

Comment: Your title makes no sense (the "for all $x,y\in D$" part). You should write this as $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in D$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your title is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, take any function of the form
$$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d},$$
where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. Now:
$$y=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \implies x=\frac{b-dy}{cy-a}$$
So, any function of that family with $a=-d$ satisfies what you are looking for.

---

**EDIT:**
In fact, note that $f$ is an invertible function such that $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, for all $x\in D$. You can consider another family, which also includes the examples by [DiegoMath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64437/diegomath). For any invertible function $g$ (probably, with some restrictions to be well defined) you have:
$$y=g^{-1}(f(g(x))) \implies x=g^{-1}(f(g(y))).$$
The example by DiegoMath takes $g(x)=e^x$.

Comment: This is realy nice, because it includes the first three examples of DiegoMath.

Comment: @Physics I recommend you the following article: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/education/wiener.pdf and the lecture of the Winkler's book: https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Functional%20Equations%20and%20How%20To%20Solve%20Them%20-%20Christopher%20G.%20Small.pdf

Comment: @Physics See my edit, where I include a generalization for the fourth one.

Comment: Ha, we did the same thing at the same time, but yours being even more general than mine.