# real values of $x$ which satisfy the equation $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}=x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, radicals, nested-radicals

> All real values of $x$ which satisfy the equation $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}=x$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Here $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}} = x>0$

Now Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}\;,$ Then equation convert into $f(f(f(x)))=x$

Now Here $f(x)=x$ be one function which satisfy above equation.

My question is how can we calculate other function which satisfy above functional equation.

Help required, Thanks

Comment: If You had $f(x)=x$, for some $x$, then $f^{\circ 3}(x)=x$ as well. So you can find one solution by solving $x=\sqrt{1+x}$. You are trying to solve a degree 8 equation, and finding the corresponding solutions will reduce it to a degree 4 equation.

Comment: This is a good question!

Comment: the title of the post should match the question in the post.

Comment: @miracle173: The title does match the question; OP is just badly mistaken about what the question means.

Comment: @EricWofsey The question is "how can we calculate other function which satisfy above functional equation" and the funtional equation is "f(f(f(x)))=x$. So the  title does not match.

Comment: There is no substantial relationship between finding $x$ which satisfies $f(f(f(x)))=x$ where $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ and finding a function $f(x)$ which satisfies $f(f(f(x)))=x$ for all $x$

Comment: If you want an alternative solution to the functional equation $f(f(f(x)))=x$, try $f(1)=2, f(2)=17, f(17)=1$ and $f(x)=x$ otherwise.  All solutions will essentially be of this form, involving arbitrary triples or leaving values unchanged.

Comment: You have spotted that any zero of $g(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}-x$ must have $x \ge 0$.  See that $g(x)$ is continuous and has $g'(x)= \frac{1}{8\cdot \sqrt{x+1}\cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{x+1}+1}\cdot \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x+1}+1}+1}}-1 \le \frac18-1 \lt 0$ for $x \ge 0$, so there is at most a single solution.  That solution also satisfies $\sqrt{1+x}=x$ and is $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: @Ghartal: I don't think so. If you read the comments to the question and the answer you can see that the question is very unclear. Actually the answer consists of two answers because Jennifer is not sure what the question is. The OP ignores that this question in unclear and does not try to improve this. I think the best is to vote it down until the OP improves the question.

Comment: In your post you also asked about functional equation $f(f(f(x)))=x$.
See here: [3rd iterate of a continuous function equals identity function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/114403).
Also [other posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/114403).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With your remark $x=\sqrt{1+x}$ should lead to a solution.

$$x=\sqrt{1+x} \iff x^2=1+x  \iff x^2-x-1=0 \iff x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$$

But $x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ is the only positive solution. We verify that it is indeed solution by using long division :

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}} = x\iff \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}=x^2-1 \iff \sqrt{1+x}=x^4-2x^2\\\iff x+1=x^8-4x^6+4x^4 \iff x^8-4x^6+4x^4-x-1=0$$

$$x^8-4x^6+4x^4-x-1=(x^2-x-1)(x^6+x^5-2x^4-x^3+x^2+1)$$

Let $g(x)=x^6+x^5-2x^4-x^3+x^2+1$, notice that $\forall x>0, g'(x)>0$, so $g$ is strictly increasing and $g(0)=1>0$, so $g(x)=0$ has no solution on $\mathbb{R}^{*+}$.

Finally $x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ is the only solution to the problem.

---

**Notes**  : 
The functional equation $\;(f \circ f \circ f)(x) = x,\forall x>0$ only has one continuous solution : $f(x)=x$.

> By studying the domain, you have $f : \mathbb{R}^{*+} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^{*+}$.
>
> $\forall x \in  \mathbb{R}^{*+}$ the image by $f$ of $f(f(x))$ is $x$ so
>   $f$ is onto. Also if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=f(f(f(a)))=f(f(f(b)))=b$, so
>   $f$ is injective. So $f$ is one to one. If $f$ is decreasing $f\circ f$ is increasing and $f\circ f\circ f$ is decrasing, but $id$ is
>   increasing, it is absurd, so $f$ is strictly increasing.
>
> Suppose $f(x)>x$, since $f$ is strictly increasing $f(f(x))>f(x)>x$,
>   so $x=f(f(f(x))>f(f(x))>f(x)>x$, it is impossible. In the same way
>    $f(x)<x$ is impossible, so $\forall x, f(x)=x$. So $f=id$.

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. In the link, $f$ satisfies the property for ALL $x$.

Comment: @Aravind I posted an adapted proof

Comment: Ah! I see now. Here, we already know that $f$ is strictly increasing in $x > 0$, so we could also use that.

Comment: @EricWofsey I have to justify why only $x=\sqrt{1+x}$ is the only expression which leads to solutions, I don't see why it should be removed, can you explain me please ?

Comment: The problem statement does not tell you that $f(f(f(x)))=x$ for all $x$, it just asks you to find the values of $x$ for which this is true.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh I see thank you very much !

Comment: @EricWofsey: No, the question is which functions satisfy $f(f(f(x)))=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Jennifer: Do you say if a function is not increasing than it is strictly increasing? That is wrong.

Comment: @Jennifer  the question is which functions satisfy $f(f(f(x)))=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: @miracle173 It was saying that if a continuous 1 to 1 function on $\mathbb{R}$ is not deacreasing then it is strictly increasing. The fact that it i was 1 to 1 was the key

Comment: @miracle173 Well I let the two solutions since the question is not really clear

Comment: @Jennifer: I think it makes sense to ask the OP to improve his question before one answers the question.

Comment: @miracle173 I am really sorry I did not notice the uncleariness of the question on the first sight when I wrote the first answer.

Comment: This is a good answer!

Comment: @RFZ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{*+}, \exists y(=f(f(x))) \in \mathbb{R}^{*+}$ such that $x=f(y)$, so by definition $f$ is onto.

Comment: @Jennifer: g(x) is wrong. compare to S.Das's answer.

Comment: @miracle173 fixed thank you

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align}\sqrt{1+{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}}=x&\implies \sqrt{1+{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}}=x\\&\implies \left(1+{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}\right)=x^2\\&\implies\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}=x^2-1\\&\implies 1+\sqrt{1+x}=x^4-2x^2+1\\&\implies \sqrt{1+x}=x^4-2x^2\\&\implies 1+x=x^4(x^2-2)^2\\&\implies 1+x=x^4(x^4-4x^2+4)\\&\implies x^8-4x^6+4x^4-x-1=0\end{align}Now observe that ,  $$x^8-4x^6+4x^4-x-1=x^8\color{red}{-x^7}-x^6\color{red}{+x^7}-x^6\color{blue}{-x^5}-2x^6\color{blue}{+2x^5}+2x^4\color{blue}{-x^5}+x^4\color{green}{+x^3}+x^4\color{green}{-x^3}\color{violet}{-x^2}\color{violet}{+x^2}-x-1$$Consequently, $$x^8-4x^6+4x^4-x-1=0\implies (x^2-x-1)(x^6+x^5-2x^4-x^3+x^2+1)$$Now observe that the function $$g(x)=x^6+x^5-2x^4-x^3+x^2+1=\left(x^3-1\right)^2+\left(x-1\right)^2\,x^3+x^2 >0$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$. So $(x^2-x-1)=0$ and hence $x=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the only positive solution.

Comment: How do you know $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Isn't this answer already included in Jennifer's answer?

Comment: @miracle173: Actually. I didn't notice the edit that was being made in Jennifer's answer as I was writing my answer. So, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @EricWofsey: edited the post so one can see that g(x)>0

Answer (score 3):

Let $1+x=y^2$, where $y>0$ and $1+y=z^2$, where $z>0$.

Hence, $1+z=x^2$, where $x>0$.

Thus, $x-y=(y-z)(y+z)$ and $y-z=(z-x)(z+x)$.

1. Let $x>y$. Hence, $y>z$, which says that $z>x$. It's contradiction.
2. Let $x<y$. Hence, $y<z$, which says that $z<x$. It's contradiction again.

Id est, $x=y=z$ and $x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$.