# Prove or disprove that $f$ is an identity function if $f(f(f(x))) = x$ and $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a continuous function in $\mathbb R$ satisfying the relation 
$f(f(f(x))) = x$, for all $x \in \mathbb R$. 
Prove or disprove that $f$ is an identity function.

Comment: Please read about [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Andres was kind enough to do it for you this time, but you've asked enough questions here (and are evidently familiar with LaTeX at least somewhat from your use of \mathbb), that you should do it yourself in the future.

Comment: Okay, i will mind it.

Comment: Some ideas: The function is obviously injective. Injective continuous function from $\Bbb R$ to itself are known to be strictly monotone.

Comment: People nowadays vote up a question that the OP shows no effort in solving?

Comment: I have no idea, how to solve it. For this reason i do not show anything.

Comment: See also [3rd iterate of a continuous function equals identity function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114403) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/114403).

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ such that $f(x) \neq x$. Let $y=f(x)$.

Suppose that $x<y$.

$f$ is bijective from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb R$ (since $f \circ f^2 = f^2 \circ f= \textrm{Id}_{\mathbb R}$) and then strictly monotone (by continuity). By composition $f$ is strictly increasing. Indeed, if $f$ is non increasing, then $x_1 < x_2 \implies f(x_1) > f(x_2) \implies f(f(x_1))<f(f(x_2) \implies f(f(f(x_1))) > f(f(f(x_2))) \implies x_1 > x_2$, which is absurd.

$x < y$ gives $f(x) < f(y)$ and then $f(f(x)) < f(f(y)) = f(f(f(x))) = x$.

But $f(x)=y$ which gives $f(y) < x < y = f(x)$. Then $f(y) < f(x)$ which is absurd because $f$ is supposed to be non decreasing.

We treat the case $y<x$ in the same way.

Comment: "By composition $f$ is strictly increasing." What do you mean by this?

Comment: +++ gives + and --- gives -, since fff(x)=x is increasing this is the + one.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I edited the post to answer your question. As zwim said when you compose an increasing and a decreasing function you get an decreasing function...

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I'll discuss the conditions of application of the theorem.

You have to explicit the range of $f$, because $f:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb C,\ f(x)=jx$

with $j^3=1$ is continuous over $\mathbb R$ and verifies $f(f(f(x)))=j^3x=x\ $ and yet is not the identity function.

It's not completely clear in your statement that $f$ range is $\mathbb R$.

Note that continuity is essential here, for instance the function below verifies $f^3=Id$ :
$f(x)=\big(x+1\pmod 3\big)+3n\quad x\in[3n,3n+3[$

It is continuous almost everywhere, but the countable discontinuities at $3n+2$ allows for global non-monotonicity of the function $f$ even if it is locally increasing away from these points.