# Non-trivial solutions of a functional equation $(f \circ f \circ f)(x)=x$

Tags: functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition, inverse-function

I have come to this from the topic of self-inverse functions. Let's consider a more complicated case where:

$$(f \circ f \circ f)(x)=x \tag{1}$$

Also assume that $f(x)$ is continuous on some non-empty interval, and $f^{-1}(x)$ exists on this interval.

Then it also follows:

$$(f \circ f)(x)=f^{-1} (x)$$

$$f(x)=(f^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(x)$$

$$x=(f^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(x)$$

A trivial solution:

$$f(x)=x$$

And one non-trivial I know:

$$f(x)=x^{\exp (\pm 2 \pi i/3)}$$

Can we find any other non-trivial solutions? I would like both examples of particular solutions and the more general methods of finding them.

---

Update: dxiv offered another nontrivial solution (I guess $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq 1$):

$$f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$$

mercio provided a link to another related question: [3rd iterate of a continuous function equals identity function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/3rd-iterate-of-a-continuous-function-equals-identity-function/), which shows that if we require the function to be continuous and for the equation to hold on the whole real line, then only the trivial solution exists.

Which is why I do not require that, I'm fine with any interval $[a,b]$ with $a \neq b$.

Comment: $f(x) = c$ isn't a solution, since $f\circ f \circ f (c+1) = c ≠ c+1$

Comment: Your question said $f(f(f(x)))=x$. Suppose $c=1$, for instance.  Then $f(f(f(2)))=f(f(1))=f(1)=1\neq 2$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor, god, I'm so sorry, I have no idea why I didn't see this. Honestly, it's embarrassing, I shouldn't ask questions at 2am

Comment: @YuriyS its alright, its really late here Im surprised I saw it (!) gl with the question

Comment: @YuriyS $\,f(x) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{x}\,$ will work on $\,\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0,1\}\,$ i.e. unless you require the domain to be all $\,\mathbb{R}\,$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/3rd-iterate-of-a-continuous-function-equals-identity-function/

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/321911813055.pdf.bannered.pdf) ("There are only nine finite groups of fractional linear transformations with integer coefficients" by Dresden), if we want linear fractional transformations with integer coefficients (who doesn't?), all are conjugate to $\dfrac{-1}{x+1}$ (or, equivalently, to the example given by @dxiv)

Comment: Draw a freehand graph of an invertible function, and use that to conjugate your known non-trivial solutions into something else. For example, $\exp\left(1-{1\over\ln x}\right)$ will do.

Comment: The proof in the linked question works for any interval.

Comment: Perhaps because it's too trivial, you seem to have overlooked $f(x)=\omega x$ where $\omega^3=1$, even though you seem to have $x^\omega$ such that $${{x^\omega}^\omega}^\omega=x$$

Comment: Here is an answer in terms of Möbius-Functions and has some generic rule to construct such functions. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4467402/746312

Comment: I have this example already. Unless you mean $\omega$ which are not in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: I can't see that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a non-singular $2\times2$ matrix and let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be 3rd roots of unity, and let

$$M
= \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}
:=A\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{pmatrix}A^{-1}
\tag 1$$
Then the [Linear Fractional Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation)

$$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
satisfies $f^3=id$.  This is due to the correspondence between matrices and Möbius-Transformations, see for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4467402/746312) for more details.