# Can a non-linear transformation iterate into a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

This is for help on a linear algebra homework question.
I am trying to find an example of a function that maps from $X\to X$ that is not a linear transformation, but there exists an $f^n$ that is a linear transformation.

This means that $f^1$ is not linear, but $f(f(\ldots f(x)\ldots)$ is linear for a defined $n$ value.

I have tried various polynomials and they do not seem to work. I do not think exponents work here. Additionally, I have tried trigonometric functions and they also do not work.

Looking for some hints to point me towards the right direction, thanks.

Comment: If you consider the identity transformation then there are many such functions. For example $f(x) = 1/x$ with $n$ even. For $n=3$, this is impossible for continuous $f$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/3rd-iterate-of-a-continuous-function-equals-identity-function

Comment: @whpowell96 Would 1/x be a function from R->R? No right? because 0 is not mapped to any value and would leave the function without an output?

Comment: How about $x\mapsto 1-x$? It is not a linear transformation since $0$ does not map to $0$.

Comment: Yeah that does work, thank you for offering input.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at a solution:
To circumvent the issue of undefined inputs, I have decided to use a piecewise function.

We can see that f:R->R, where f(x)=1/x, when x!=0 and f(x)=0 when x=0, is not a linear transformation.
This is because f(x+y)=1/(x+y)!=1/x+1/y, showing that f(x+y)!=f(x)+f(y).

However, f(f(x))=1/(1/x))=x, or the identity transformation.

We can see that x=0 works as well because f(f(0))=f(0)=0, also satisfying the condition.